# VS Code settings.json error: $ref'/definitions/jspmDefinition'in'vscode://schemas/settings/user' can not be s

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having an issue with my settings.json in VSCode where it is throwing the following error.

```
$ref '/definitions/jspmDefinition' in 'vscode://schemas/settings/user' can not be resolved.
```

I have run a debug where it shows that the below.

```
Info: Start process (11:47:32 AM)
Error: 
/Users/zachhoferitza/Library/Application Support/Code/User/node_aacfea1700caf.tmp:2
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47

Info: End process (11:47:32 AM)
```

Everything looks in order and the error started a couple of days ago. I have gone through some of my extensions such as Prettier and uninstalled them and reinstalled, this did not fix the issue. Any help would be appreciated. [Please click here to see a snapshot of my vscode if needed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO7i8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue.

TL, DR: helped removal of `hookyqr.createmodule` plugin

Tried to search for substring `` in vscode repo https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/search?q=jspmDefinition but got no luck (no found entries)

then I tried to search at my `.vscode` dir for this substring:

```
~/.vscode $ rg 'jspmDefinition' .
./extensions/hookyqr.createmodule-0.0.5/package.json
296:                "jspmDefinition": {
334:                            "$ref": "#/definitions/jspmDefinition"
```

That's it! Also, I created an issue about that: https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeCreateModule/issues/4